# How should I configure express server to handle websocket traffic?

Tags: javascript, express, websocket, haproxy, sockjs

I'm trying to build an internal chat application for one of my projects.

I am planning to use a separate, dedicated instance of express server to handle the traffic for the chat, as opposed to using the main server to do everything.

What would be the most efficient way to configure the server to handle the traffic that will be coming into the chat server?